# Querying MongoDB Nested Fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express, mongoose

**EDIT**

I've now realised that the session documents have a FIELD of `session` and a VALUE of everything else. So `cookie: { passport: { user:... } } }` aren't nested objects, they're all just one big string.

So now I can use a $regex query to find what I need:

```
Session.find({
    'session': {$regex : ".*jane@gmail.com.*"}
  }, function(error, session){
```

========= Original Question ==========

I'm using connect-mongo to save users' sessions to MongoDB, and I want to query the `session` collection to find out if a user has an active session.

The username is stored in the collection under `sessions.cookie.passport.user` but my queries are coming back empty.

Here's an example session document:

```
{
    "_id": "orxJPolqKQ11rZdYhTKMuS90G-zDrrKk",
    "session":
    "{
      \"cookie\":{
        \"originalMaxAge\":null,\"expires\":null,\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},
        \"flash\":{},
        \"passport\":{
          \"user\":\"jane@email.com\"   // <- This is what I want!
        }                                // ... More info here...
```

The queries I've tried so far:

```
Session.find({
    "session.cookie.passport.user": "jane@gmail.com"
  }, function(error, session){
```

and,

```
Session.find({
    "session.cookie.passport": {"user": "jane@gmail.com"}
  }, function(error, session){
```

and,

```
Session.find({
    session: {
      cookie: {
        passport: {
          user: "jane@gmail.com"
        }
      }
    }
  }, function(error, session){
```

and,

```
Session.find({
    "session": {
      "cookie": {
        "passport": {
          "user": "jane@gmail.com"
        }
      }
    }
  }, function(error, session){
```

then I tried simpler queries to build them up step-by-step (this next one returns all documents):

```
Session.find({
    "session": {$exists: true}
  }, function(error, session){
```

But then this one returns zero documents:

```
Session.find({
    "session.cookie": {$exists: true}
  }, function(error, session){
```

How can I query the database to retrieve a session by a given username?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
Session.find({
    "session.cookie.passport.user": "jane@gmail.com"
  }, function(error, session){
```

Comment: Thanks Kalman. I had already tried that query as well (I just tried it again to make sure), but it's also not working. I've updated my OP to include that attempt.